# How can a Castle generate gold to help adventurers in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Through some randomness and a deck of many things, I have acquired a small castle.

I am very new to pathfinder/D&D as is the rest of my group.

The group overall is starved for gold, me especially. Everyone has around 2000 gold and I have 0 (the deck destroyed everything non-magical I owned). We are all level 6 to 7.

I have heard that a castle could be used to generate gold for the group somehow. Can anyone explain this in detail for a newbie? Apparently the castle is abandoned, but has land.

If the castle can't be used for gold generation, what other ways could the castle benefit the group?

The GM likes to surprise us, so is quite tight lipped about everything. Since the castle came into existance rather randomly, I doubt it'd be a focal point to the campaign and thus I would like to limit how much attention it would require.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - I'm not voting to close this question, as I think "How can a castle be used to generate money in Pathfinder?" is an answerable question... but others likely will. RPG.SE isn't a traditional discussion forum, but a Q&A site with a specific style. I strongly recommend the [tour] to familiarize yourself. In this case, you'll probably get a better response if you 1) narrow down your question and clarify exactly what it is you're looking for, and 2) add more context about the setting and style of the campaign - how much are you all willing to focus on this, esp. the GM?

Comment: Are these changes ok?

Comment: Makes sense to me... though there are so many conceivable uses for a castle, you should probably stick with the gold angle.